# Проверка условия на его количество в Python

Tags: python

Хотел бы узнать, как в операцию if добавить проверку условий на количество.
К примеру:

```
print(a)
print(a)
print(a)
if *если print(a) выполнилось три раза*:
    print(b)
```

Буду благодарен.

Comment: а как в этом коде print может выполниться другое кол-во раз?

Comment: Это просто пример. Понятно, что в коде другие действия) Но суть та же. Надо проверить, чтобы какое-либо действие если повторялось n количество раз, то выполнялось другое.

Comment: добавьте счетчик. При выполнении каждого действия увеличивайте на 1.

Comment: такой функции нет, но в реальном коде это можно понять по другим признакам. Или складывайте вывод в буфер и анализируйте его, а выводите в конце

Comment: Я делаю, так сказать, бота для бесед ВК. Пока сильно не разбираюсь, по-этому и спрашиваю. Хотелось бы, что при флуде тремя одинаковыми сообщениями писал бот что-либо. C счетчиком не вариант, потому что бот должен засчитывать повторное действие лишь тогда, когда оно повторяется с предыдущим 3 раза.

Comment: для этого и нужен счетчик. вы считаете каждое сообщение. если оно повторяется - увеличиваете счетчик. пока он не достигнет нужного значения.

Comment: так берите сообщение пользователя и сравнивайте с предыдущими двумя, если совпадают - отправляйте предупреждение о флуде или баньте его...

Answer (score 1):

Типа если тебе нужно вывести список из N количества то можно сделать так

```
i = 'Ваш текст или не текст'
n = 15 #Это пример, и количество раз выведеного
for i in range(n):
  print(i)
```

А то что ты спрашиваешь, то тут не понятно
Как вариант можно создасть список `list = []` И вносить туда все переменные и в итоге подсчитать все

```
list = []
def list_(a):
  print(a)
  list.append(a)
#Дальше когда вызывается функция переменная 'a' добавляется в список 'list'

def count_list():
  print(list.count())
count_list()
#дальше мы просто подсчитываем количество элементов в списке
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Только не называйте переменные ключевыми словами питона, `list` - это плохое название для переменной.